# Creating a OOXML document with Track Changes enabled

Tags: openxml

How do I create a .docx with track changes enabled? I was told inside `word/settings.xml` I should modify `w:proofState` but all info in online docs of OOXML I find about that property is related to grammar and spell checking, but nothing about enabling tracking changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in `word/settings.xml` but the element you are looking for is `w:trackRevisions`.

To do this in C# using the OpenXML SDK you can use the [`TrackRevisions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.trackrevisions(v=office.15).aspx) class. The following code will create a document with one paragraph and with change tracking turned on:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    // Add a new main document part. 
    package.AddMainDocumentPart();

    //create a body and a paragraph
    Body body = new Body();
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    paragraph.AppendChild(new Run(new Text("This document should have change tracking switched on")));
    body.AppendChild(paragraph);
    package.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(body);

    //change tracking code
    DocumentSettingsPart documentSettingsPart = package.MainDocumentPart.AddNewPart<DocumentSettingsPart>();
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    TrackRevisions trackRevisions = new TrackRevisions();
    settings.Append(trackRevisions);
    documentSettingsPart.Settings = settings;

    // Save changes to the main document part. 
    package.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```